# How to make a custom annotation for trimmed field in entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot and Java 8, have multiple models: DTOs, Entities, ViewModels, etc, but need get and save the description of a person, but the description need trim the value, by example:

```java
    @Size(min=0, max=1024)
    private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return ((this.description != null) ? this.description.trim() : null);
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = ((description != null) ? description.trim() : null);
    }
```

I make a custom annotation like as `@Trimmed` for automatize it like as:

```java
    @Trimmed
    @Size(min=0, max=1024)
    private String description;
```

I try make the interface and the aspect:

**Trimmed.java**

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Trimmed {
}
```

**TrimmedAspect.java**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class TrimmedAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(Trimmed)")
    public Object requestIntercept ...

}
```

But, how to make the aspect? in the internet can find examples using functions and class declarations but no fields when get and set values.

How to can made this?

Answer (score 1):

I just made an example custom annotation with AOP, in my component Event responsible for this: I just tried this code maybe it helps: it will be executed after the user is created

```
 @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* ypour.package..*(..))", returning = "retVal")
    public void requestIntercept(JoinPoint pjp, Object retVal) throws JsonProcessingException {

        //----- your implementation here 
            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: But the joinpoint points to all the functions, in my entities I have only some fields that require cleaning, not all, anyway this annotation would have to apply to all the getters functions instead of the variable, I would have to make another annotation for the getters and it would fill the functions with annotations, the idea was to control the values from the declared variables as well as for example the validators.

Comment: Solve this using `@AfterReturning(value="@annotation(TrimGetterString)", returning="retVal")` only for getters functions, but i want apply the annotation in the variable.